# Bought currency for the wrong region - what are my options?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I live in Australia and accidentally bought a US $20 Xbox gift card. It's my first time buying one so I wasn't really sure what to do. To make matters worse, I've already redeemed it so it's stuck in my account. I've tried changing my locale online to US but when I try purchasing it shows up with AU currency and I'm not sure if it will take money from the gift card or my credit card.

What are my options? My 360 is so old I wouldn't even mind doing a mod so that the money doesn't go to waste

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe contact Microsoft? I *think* we cannot do anything

Comment: Would changing the region on the console fix the issue? Using the account migration or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 1):

After you sign in and go to My Account on the Xbox live website, you can go to Payment & Billing. There it should say how much money was credited to your account. I would imagine that they would credit you the equivalent of $20US in Australian dollars, so like $25.83. If this is not the case, I would contact Microsoft but their system should be smart enough to know the location where your account was created.

Comment: Thanks for the response. They didn't credit anything as my microsoft account credit is still $0. Plus, I removed my CC as payment options to force it to use the gift card but it just says I have no valid payment method.